# How can I debug this Internet Explorer issue?

Tags: asp.net, security, internet-explorer, iis

I have a Web Application (ASP.NET C# for .NET 3.5) that uses the **Session object** to store, amount little things the **debug information** so when things go wrong, this is the first place to go.

The process is simple actually,

no matter what browser (except IE), when I navigate to a page, in the Debug Log I have data, just like the one show below

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1048.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1048.png)

problem is that in **Internet Explorer, the Debug Log is always blank** (blank as no information, not no html code)

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1051.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-14_1051.png)

> What can I do?

I tried several Security settings of IE8:

- add the site (machine name) to **Trusted Sites**
- disable **Protect Mode**
- set Local intranet security level to **LOW**
- set **Accept All Cookies** under Privacy
- checked the **Allow Active Content** under Advanced tab

I really don't know what more can I do :-(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the information present in the source code? Do you have an IE specific stylesheet that may be hiding the results?

Comment: @belexandre can you please tell us witch program you use for read this debug infos ? Do you need to read the info in real time - is for you ?

Comment: @James it's only a dump of the Session Object (but in a nice presentation) - @Aristos what program?

Comment: If its a dump of the session then your problem is server side, unless you are streaming the session object via xml/ajax to the client.

Comment: @James if that was the case, Firefox, Safari and Opera would fail the same action, correct? But they don't as you can see the 1st screenshot, only IE8 fails :(

Comment: yeah wierd. Can you dump the html that contains the table onto a url somewhere ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - a web debugging proxy - to check traffic between IE and your site. Also, if you can, try other versions of IE on different machines/networks to see if it's a global problem, or just related to one browser. And don't forget you can hit F12 to enable developer console in IE.

Comment: I do... it says nothing regarding this as this is a server thingy. Fiddler / FireBug for FF only catch requests and responses, and in my example, all I do is load a page, not even click or request an action. HTML is show well on all browsers, just the Session Object is not displayed on IE browser :(